# How to construct a balanced search tree?

Tags: trees

I'm not sure how to construct a balanced search tree out of a few numbers and their associated search probabilities.

Please explain using the following example:

```
15 0.2
10 0.22
107 0.02
30 0.05
12 0.18
105 0.25
120 0.08
```

Comment: A balanced search tree does not take the search probabilities into account. You are probably after an optimal search tree, which can be imbalanced.

Comment: The question asked for what u said also, which I can do. However, I do want an algorithm for constructing a/the balanced tree, even if it means ignoring their probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

To build a balanced search tree, sort the array and recursively pick the medians.

10 12 15 **30** 105 107 120

10 **12** 15 30 105 **107** 120

**10** 12 **15** 30 **105** 107 **120**

Comment: Thanks. What if I only do one iteration, wouldn't this tree be balanced?

10 12 15 30 105 107 120

Comment: @AhmadAbdelzaher What you show is not a tree, it's an array.

Comment: picture an upside down v with 30 is the root, can you see it?

Comment: I meant for the left side 30 parent of 15, parent of 12, of 10. Perfect upside down v.(sorry I'm on phone)

Comment: U show 30 parent of 12 and from 12 it's an upside v of 10 and 15 from left to right. I'm talking about 30 parent of 15,...etc, no other branches except for the big upside down v.

Comment: @AhmadAbdelzaher: a single upside down V is not balanced at all. It is very close to the most imbalanced which is possible.

Comment: what defines a balanced tree? isn't it the same height (depth)?

Comment: @AhmadAbdelzaher: that's one possible definition, there are others. But according to it, the V is imbalanced.